# how to get listbox selected item value passing to another page for windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Hi am using xaml file given below.I want to get selected item value to details view.

```
<StackPanel Width="Auto">
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"  Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="NotchsList11_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                          <Border BorderBrush="White" Margin="0,0,8,0" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="152" Height="90"  Stretch="Fill"  VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
                          </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                         </ListBox>
                      </StackPanel>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="Auto">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Titles}"   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="NotchsList11_SelectionChanged">
                   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        </StackPanel>
                          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <Border BorderBrush="White" Margin="0,0,8,0"
                                            BorderThickness="1"> 
                                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  Width="152" Height="80" Padding="5,10,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>    
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
```

My Main.Cs  Code

```
private void NotchsList11_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Test.xaml?parameter={0}",UriKind.Relative));
            //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?parameter=test", UriKind.Relative));
        }

    }
```

I used this thing i cant go to other page with selected item.
i want output like given below image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simple and efficient approach - have a `ViewModel`. When the item is selected (hook the `SelectionChanged` event handler), pass the instance to the `ViewModel` and navigate to the second page that will show the item details. Make sure that the page is bound to the `ViewModel` and simply read from the item you passed in.

Comment: hi i am not using MVVM type.I passing values directly to another page.

Comment: It's one of your better options (very basic MVVM). Refer to this answer for more options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4728343/303696